# what is the best method to multi request with callback or promise on node.js

Tags: node.js, list, callback, promise

I have a situation. I use Node.js to connect to a special hardware. let assume that I have two functions to access the hardware.

```
hardware.send('command');
hardware.on('responce', callback);
```

At first, I made a class to interface this to the application layer like this (I write simplified code over here for better understanding)

```
class AccessHardware {
    constructor() {    
    }
    updateData(callback) {        
        hardware.on('responce', callback);        
        hardware.send('command');
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that if there are multiple requests from the application layer to this access layer, they should not send multiple 'command' to the hardware. Instead, they should send one command and all of those callbacks can be served once the hardware answer the command.

So I update the code something like this:

```
class AccessHardware {
    constructor() {
        this.callbackList = [];
        hardware.on('responce', (value) => {
            while (this.callbackList.length > 0) {
                this.callbackList.pop()(value);
            }
        });        
    }
    updateData(callback) {  
        if (this.callbackList.length == 0) {                    
            hardware.send('command');
        }
        this.callbackList.push(callback);
    }
}
```

Of course, I prefer to use promise to handle the situation. so what is your suggestion to write this code with promise? 
Next question, is this approach to make a 'list of callbacks' good?

Comment: So all `updateData()` calls send the same command, and they shouldn't send a command while one still is in flight? So that you get the maximum rate of commands being sent, with results being arbitrarily being shared amongst consecutive calls? Do you expect the results to change? If yes, sharing doesn't sound like a good idea, if no, why do you want to send multiple commands at all instead of sharing the single result?

Comment: @Bergi well, application layer has multiple web-based clients, so it's possible that they all ask the same command. After the result becomes ready (it takes about 15 seconds) application should send the result to all clients. that is the reason all commands are same but there are multiple requests

Comment: Yes, but if another clients asks the same command after 30s, would it really need to run the command again? Couldn't it just return the already available result that got sent to the other clients before?

Comment: @Bergi no, it should always get a new query because the state of the hardware may get changed during this time.

Comment: OK, it's just that when the state of the hardware changes after 10s (while the first command is still running) a client that asks at 15s still gets the old result. This seemed somewhat arbitrary to me, I'd rather recommend a generic debounce function for that which clears its cache after a fixed time.

Answer (score 1):

> I prefer to use promise to handle the situation. So what is your suggestion to write this code with promise?

You'd store a promise in your instance that will be shared between all method callers that want to share the same result:

```
class AccessHardware {
    constructor(hardware) {
        this.hardware = hardware;
        this.responsePromise = null;
    }
    updateData() {  
        if (!this.responsePromise) {
            this.responsePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                this.hardware.on('responce', resolve);
                this.hardware.send('command');
            });
            this.responsePromise.finally(() => {
                this.responsePromise = null; // clear cache as soon as command is done
            });
        }       
        return this.responsePromise;
    }
}
```

Btw, if `hardware` is a global variable, there's no reason to use a `class` here.

> Is the current solution to make a 'list of callbacks' good?

Yes, that's fine as well for a non-promise approach.